# GitHub's Webhooks is sending nonsense events

Tags: github, webhooks

I have a webhook on `issues` for github and I update the body of the issue from within my application using `PATCH` request. The rate is not very fast, like a request every few seconds. Most of the times it works, yet some of the times GitHub sends my hook a nonsense payload which has the body text before my edit in both `body` and `changes.body.from` fields as if there was a change which changed nothing. At the same time:

- The responce to my `PATCH` displays new body correctly.
- The issue itself on GitHub gets updated properly.
- No follow up webhook procs with correct body happen.

Anybody has an idea what I could be hitting here?

Thanks in advance.